# Null pointer exception while reading from HBase

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, cloudera, bigdata

Getting a weird NullPointerException randomly while scanning the HBase table. Here's the sample code:

```
try (final ResultScanner scanner = table.getScanner(scan)) {

    Result res;
    while ((res = scanner.next()) != null) {
            ...
    }
```

For scanner.next() I get the following exception when I fire multiple queries against the SAME table within a very short span of time. The same code is working in normal conditions, that is, when I don't fire too many requests against any table.

> 02:37:29,461 ERROR Executor:96 - Exception in task 0.0 in stage 1.0
>   (TID 1)  530967java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.setClose(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:101)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.nextScanner(ClientScanner.java:251)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.possiblyNextScanner(ClientScanner.java:235)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.loadCache(ClientScanner.java:524)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.next(ClientScanner.java:358)
>     at
>
> ```
>   ... 19 more
> ```

I tried increasing lease period, RPC timeout, and even region server IPC read thread pool size. There's no specific error in HBase logs except for expired lease. I am on CDH 5.5.

Comment: In case this info has any relevance but often I have seen this error while performing 2791 st scan. Any limitation there?

Comment: maybe your can share more of your code. so you're running multiple threads to query from the same table?

Comment: It's through a Spark job hence it might be run in threads. The code given above is all that I have written.

Comment: Seems to be working after I avoided splitting the table. Doesn't sound logical, but it works, needs further investigation.

Comment: Did further investigation reveal anything else?

Comment: It looks like this question is missing an [mcve] that would make it answerable. Voting to put on hold for now, edits welcome.